# vscode neovim plugin is changing variable color behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim, neovim-plugin

I like neovim default behavior a bit more than vim default behavior so I switched plugins to neovim but neovim has an additional side effect of changing the default behavior for variables when I have a cursor over them.

I want to disable the color changes.

Here's an image without the plugin (desired)

[image: Without the plugin]

Image with the plugin (not desired)

[image]

Anybody else dealt with this? I didn't see any settings in neovim that suggests this is an optional feature.

Comment: Possibly related but I'm only ~10% sure: https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/311

Comment: I followed the solution for this issue which recommends installing a plugin but unfortunately that didn't solve the problem (it does highlight my current variable though haha)